# Read directly from zip VS extracting it

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I'm using APK Expansion Files to download a lot of images to display them. The app uses these images a lot.
Is using `ZipResourceFile` to read the images from the zip file have bad performance in comparison to extracting once and then read them directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its better u go for extracting, if the images or contents of the zip are reused continuosly. Extracting will be a 1time process from next time u can read directly from file. But reading huge content from zip, can affect ur memory always, as the zip object will be stored in memory or ull hv to reinitialte the zip object when u need to read the file .